# Add Open Image action to QGIS table when folder has a space/special characters

Tags: qgis

It's easy to add an action in QGIS to open an image but when the folder has a space in it (and special characters) how do you write the action command?

[image]

```
R:\Video Library\Transport\Road Network - DVRs\2021 05 (May) Data\Douglas SC June 2021\[%Road_Name%]\Photos\[%Photo_Name%]
```

I have also tried to escape it

```
\"R:\Video Library\Transport\Road Network - DVRs\2021 05 (May) Data\Douglas SC June 2021\\"[%Road_Name%]\Photos\[%Photo_Name%]
```

but the characters just get printed when I use double or single quotes.

[image]

[image]

If it makes any difference I am using 3.20.3

Comment: Can not  reproduce the error. What command do you use in your action?

Comment: I tried it with Open and also Explore